# Route issues with ActionMailer "Missing required keys: [:locale]"

Tags: routes, actionmailer, rails-i18n

I've recently added multilanguage support to my rails app, but now all my mailers stopped working...

```
class NotificationUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'control-de-asistencia@email.us'

  def send_welcome_mail_to(user_id, password)
    @user     = User.find(user_id)
    @password = password
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Bienvenido a Timewarp')
  end
end
```

every time it reaches to

```
mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Bienvenido a Timewarp')
```

i get the following exception:

> ActionView::Template::Error:
>          No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"} missing required keys: [:locale]

Here is my code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale
  private

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}
  end

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = user_signed_in? ? current_user.language.to_sym : I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

enviroment

```
#development.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000, protocol: 'http', locale: I18n.locale }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews"
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.mandrill_username,
    password:  Rails.application.secrets.mandrill_api_key
  }
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ':locale', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
    devise_for :users

    devise_scope :user do
      authenticated :user do
        root 'dashboard#show', as: :authenticated_root
      end

      unauthenticated do
        root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
      end
    end

    root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
    get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
    get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
end
```

spec:

```
describe '#send_welcome_mail_to' do
    it 'should send mail to user' do
      user = create(:user)
      expect { NotificationUserMailer.send_welcome_mail_to(user.id, user.password).deliver }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end
  end
```

Do i have to set locale somewhere else ApplicationController.rb??. I'm really lost right now
Any help would be great.. thanks!

Comment: At least some insight where i should start looking? :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a "root_path" inside my view that wotn set the locale properly. i created the path outside the view...

```
class NotificationUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'control-de-asistencia@email.us'

  def send_welcome_mail_to(user_id, password)
    @user     = User.find(user_id)
    @password = password
   @root_url = url_for(controller: 'devise/sessions', action: 'new', locale: @user.language)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Bienvenido a Timewarp')
  end
end
```